# Review page body oddly clipped on desktop

Tags: bug, review, design

The review page body for me is weirdly clipped and scrollable horizontally, even though that's not the case for pretty much anywhere else on the site, nor is it the case for the site header. I'm on desktop on Chrome 68 (beta), if that helps.

[image: screenshot]

Comment: Looks like they missed the responsive design with review, yep.

Comment: Cross site dupe: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/344521/request-for-redesign-to-have-better-compatibility-with-1024px-wide-displays